# React native, children of ScrollView wont fill full height

Tags: flexbox, react-native

So I have a horizontal scrollview at the top of the view. The ScrollView contains nodes that have a specified width. I then have a border on the bottom of the ScrollView, like you can see in this screen cap: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcvDj.png

As you can see the child nodes of the ScrollView at the top don't reach the border. However, if I change the ScrollView to a View with `flexDirection: 'row'`, then the child nodes fill the height fine. I've tried changing a few properties on the scrollview, such as:

- Setting `padding:0` on `contentContainerStyle`
- `automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}`
- Changing the values of `contentInsets` directly

None of those seem to fix the issue.

The scrollview code & style:

```js
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  nav: {
    padding: 0,
    marginTop: 30,
    flex: 1,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#000000'
  }
});

<ScrollView
  style={[{width: screen.width}, styles.nav]}
  horizontal={true}
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={true}
  automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}>
  {dayNavItems}
</ScrollView>
```

The child components (makes up dayNavItems)

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingLeft: 15,
    paddingRight: 15,
    width: 50,
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  odd: {
    backgroundColor: '#ccc'
  },
  selected: {
    backgroundColor: '#39b54a'
  },
  text: {
    fontFamily: 'Optima'
  }
});

class DayNavItem extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    day: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    odd: React.PropTypes.bool,
    selectDay: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    selected: React.PropTypes.bool
  };

  render() {
    const d = new Date(this.props.day.created_at);
    const viewStyles = [styles.container];
    if (this.props.selected) {
      viewStyles.push(styles.selected);
    } else if (this.props.odd) {
      viewStyles.push(styles.odd);
    }
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={viewStyles} onPress={() => this.props.selectDay(this.props.day.uuid)}>
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.text}>{getMonth(d)}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.text}>{d.getDate()}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Any way you could show the code and style for the ScrollView and the parent?

Comment: Thanks for the code, checking this out now..

Comment: Have you tried setting a height for the container components? I've gotten something like what you're working on working, but I had to give the components a height property: https://rnplay.org/apps/QP4sBw

Comment: I haven't tried that yet Nader. I don't really want to given that the scrollview is flex, and so is the siblings of the scrollview.

Answer (score 273):

Adding `contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}` will do the trick.

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer. + you should set child View to flex:1 as well. height will be filled and scroll will work as well.

Comment: That's Good Answer, Can you explain to me the process? and why we use flexGrow?

Comment: @DevAS content container holds the child nodes of a scroll view. ```flexGrow``` property specifies how much the item will grow relative to the rest of the flexible items inside the same container. Setting ```flexGrow: 1``` to the content container will make the content of the container glow to fill up the full height of the container

Comment: I dont know why, but for me setting flexGrow to 0 instead of 1 did the trick.

Comment: This works! It's worth mentioning that `contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}}` will break the scrollview, on the other hand

Answer (score 17):

There is a property called `contentContainerStyle` for `ScrollView`. I just solved a similar issue where I set `flex: 1` to the `ScrollView`'s `styles`, `ScrollView`'s `contentContainerStyle`, and the child `View` component.

Comment: this can make the scroll view unable to scroll

Answer (score 10):

The other answers are correct, but just to provide a clarifying example:

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}>
  {children}
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Be aware that using `flex: 1` on your contentContainerStyle will break scrolling in situations where your content exceeds the height of your ScrollView. (You won't be able to scroll in your ScrollView)

You'll want to *only* use `flexGrow: 1` on your contentContainerStyle.

Source: I just did this in my app and Raphael's answer above fixed the issue.

Answer (score 6):

Setting `flex: 1` for ScrollView's `contentContainerStyle` property did the trick for me.

Answer (score 5):

I always end up creating this component in all my projects:

```js
import * as React from 'react'
import { ScrollView, ScrollViewProps, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

export function FullHeightScrollView(
  props: {
    children: React.ReactNode
  } & Omit<ScrollViewProps, 'contentContainerStyle'>
) {
  return (
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.grow} {...props}>
      {props.children}
    </ScrollView>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  grow: { flexGrow: 1 },
})
```

Use it in place of React Native's `ScrollView`.

Comment: Works like magic.  Spent quite awhile searching for this.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If ScrollView is wrapped inside of a SafeAreaView, put flex: 1 on SafeAreaView, this did the trick for me after hours of debugging...

Parent:

[image]

Child (styles ScrollView I implemented has nothing to do with the current issue you reported):

[image]

Comment: Setting `{flex:1} ` for the outer view did the trick for me.

Answer (score -2):

I have made a simple package for those who just want, like me, a working out of the box ScrollView, without having to apply all the time the styles to make it work properly.

https://github.com/SrBrahma/pagescrollview

Usage:

```
import { PageScrollView } from 'pagescrollview';

<PageScrollView>
  {/** Your contents */}
</PageScrollView>
```