# Scrollview whose individual child takes all remaining area

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I want to create a scrollview (in react-native app) whose individual children take the remaining space on the screen.

The goal is that, as user scrolls, he should only be shown **one** profile at a time instead of multiple profiles.

This is how my Scroll view code looks

```js
const ProfileVerticalScroll = ({
  active = 0,
  setActive,
  profileData,
  scrollViewRef,
}: Props) => {
  return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView} ref={scrollViewRef}>
      {profileData.map((el, index) => {
        return (
          <View style={styles.profile}>
            <View style={styles.profileHeadings}>
              <Text>{el.name} </Text>
              <Text>{el.profession}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.abouteMe}>
              <Text> About Me</Text>
              <Text>{el.info}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        );
      })}
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

export default ProfileVerticalScroll;
```

Where styles, for now, are just these

```js
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');
export default StyleSheet.create({
  scrollView: {},
  profile: {
    flex: 1,
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: width,
    paddingHorizontal: width * 0.05,
  },
  profileHeadings: {},
  abouteMe: {},
});
```

**Problem:** I am unable to get single children of a `ScrollView` to take up the entire screen

For example, In the below screenshot, I would want Alan to take the complete screen and further scrolling should take the user to Amanda and so on

[image]

Comment: You could make each profile's height 100% of the parent scroll container and set your scroll container to overflow-y: scroll;

Comment: Can you please elaborate? probably in answer?

Answer (score 0):

Hello have you try to set the height to min-max 100vh?
like below:

```json
profile: {
    flex: 1,
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center', 
    minHeight: '100vh',
    width: width,
    paddingHorizontal: width*0.05,
}
```

Comment: THis is react-native. 
`100vh` even on the web means full-screen height. 
There is already content above scrollview. Thanks for answering though :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to have each profile fill 100% of the container vertically and scroll through then I would do something like this:

```js
export default StyleSheet.create({
  scrollView: {
    overflowY: 'scroll',
  },
  profile: {
    height: '100%',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: width,
    paddingHorizontal: width * 0.05,
  },
  profileHeadings: {},
  abouteMe: {},
});
```

Comment: Hey, This is a react-native app. There isn't anything like overflowY in react-native app I think?

Comment: Ah sorry, it looks just like css! This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34880660/react-native-children-of-scrollview-wont-fill-full-height