# ScrollView cut off in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have encountered a problem. ScrollView is cut off at the bottom of the screen on both Android and iOS. It's "unscrollable". My code is rather simple:

```
 <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
            <Image
              style={styles.image}
              source={{ uri: constants.media_url + "/" + data.img }}
            />

            <Text style={styles.title}>{data.heading}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.published_date}>{data.published_date}</Text>

            <Text style={styles.introduction}>
              {stripHTML(data.introduction)}
            </Text>
            <RenderHtml contentWidth={width} source={source} />
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
```

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: colors.background,
    padding: 10,
    flex: 1,
  },
  image: {
    width: "100%",
    maxHeight: 270,
    height: "100%",
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 24,
    marginTop: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  introduction: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  text: {
    fontWeight: "normal",
    marginTop: 13,
  },
  published_date: {
    color: colors.gray,
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
});
```

As you can see I have used flex tricks, I've also tried padding, everything. It just doesn't work. I use only two libraries in my project: "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.4", and React Navigation.

Thank you!

Comment: Try putting particular value to image height instead of 100%.

Comment: @Thanhal image is fine. RenderHTML component is cut off.

Comment: Take one View inside scroll view and put all elements into that view and give that view marginBottom:30

Comment: @Korovjov I get this working when commented height:100% from your code.  Just try commenting height:100% since you already mentioned its maxHeight

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React native, children of ScrollView wont fill full height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34880660/react-native-children-of-scrollview-wont-fill-full-height)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after hours of searching and trying, literally, I have done it.

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <ScrollView
            style={styles.container}
            contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1, paddingBottom: 300 }}
          >
            <Image
              style={styles.image}
              source={{ uri: constants.media_url + "/" + data.img }}
            />

            <Text style={styles.title}>{data.heading}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.published_date}>{data.published_date}</Text>

            <Text style={styles.introduction}>
              {stripHTML(data.introduction)}
            </Text>
            <RenderHtml contentWidth={width} source={source} />
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
```

What I changed is I added `contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1, paddingBottom: 300 }}` to my ScrollView component. For me 300 worked, maybe you can change according to your needs.