# Stop FlatList from overflowing containing View?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-web, expo-web

Edit: Snack repro: https://snack.expo.dev/hwTTY2tQm

How do you make a FlatList stop expanding beyond its enclosing view and become scrollable while still taking all (legal) space in the enclosing view?

So far setting height to a specific number worked, but setting height to "100%" still overflows, setting flex:1 still overflows.

[image: Screenshot]

This is React Native Web.

Comment: have you tried this answer here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34880660/react-native-children-of-scrollview-wont-fill-full-height

Comment: @Guku didn't fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For flexbox to work correctly flex:1 must be maintained for every enclosing view up the hierarchy. One of my views didn't have flex:1.